# Apache 2.4, configure forward proxy with several remote proxy servers

Tags: apache

I want to setup a forward proxy that doesn't have an actual internet connection but instead forwards all requests to a set of real proxys.
The proxy_balancer_module comes to mind. We are already using this module for some reverse proxy configurations.

Basically something like this

```
AllowCONNECT 80 443

<Proxy balancer://proxycluster>
  BalancerMember http://realproxy1:1234
  BalancerMember http://realproxy2:1234
</Proxy>

ProxyRemote * balancer://proxycluster
```

The server starts but whenever I request something, I get a DNS error.

Trying www.google.com:
[proxy_connect:error] [pid 59104:tid 139869147436800] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: [client 127.0.0.1:47016] AH02327: failed to resolve hostname 'proxycluster'
[proxy:error] [pid 59104:tid 139869147436800] [client 127.0.0.1:47016] AH00898: DNS lookup failure for: proxycluster returned by www.google.com:443

It's hard to find information about this kind of configuration. The only thing that came close is another post by a user almost 2 years ago -> [Apache HTTPD ProxyRemote and Balancer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893927/apache-httpd-proxyremote-and-balancer)

Any ideas?

Comment: ended up using http://www.haproxy.org